# Is it possible to get an NSView to pass rightMouseDown: to the next responder without subclassing?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsviewcontroller

I have a view which contains a few subviews:

```
mainView
    subViewA
    subViewB
    SubViewC
```

`mainView` is an `NSView` constructed from a nib and is controlled with an `NSViewController` subclass. The subviews are standard views such as `NSTextField` and `NSImageView` and are configured to be non-editable. I want `mainView` to receive `rightMouseDown:` even when the event is triggered in one of the subviews.

The default implementation of `rightMouseDown:` in `NSResponder` passes the event to the next responder, but `NSView` changes the default behaviour and does not pass it to the next responder.

I could subclass all of the subviews but this doesn't seem like a very elegant or maintainable solution.

How can I get the subviews to pass `rightMouseDown:` messages to the next responder without subclassing all of the subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to add a subview to the `mainView` which I've called `clickCatcher`. `clickCatcher` is transparent and equal in size to `mainView` and is added so that it's the top most view:

```
[self addSubview:clickCatcher positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
```

The `XXXmouseDown:` methods of `clickCatcher` call `superview`.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually accomplished by overriding the superviews's `-hitTest:` method?

Answer (score 0):

Override NSApplication's - (void)sendEvent:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
  if([event type]== NSRightMouseDown)
    redirect to wherever
  else
    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```